# Can I drop & create db while executing pg_restore command?

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgresql-9.1, pg-restore

I am trying to execute the following command to restore db in a Docker container:

```
cmd /c "docker exec -i database-container pg_restore -C -U postgres -d employee -v < C:\\backup\\employee.tar"
```

But it throws: *"pg_restore: error: connection to database "employee" failed: FATAL:  database "employee" does not exist"* (If I create an empty database with the same name, it is created without any problem).

The reason may be:

> When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

So, is it possible to restore db using the same pg_restore command? Or should I modify it by adding drop and create commands to fix the problem?

Comment: Indeed ... ideally you'd make the other postgresql-instance to generate a dump file including the "create database" option.  How did you create the tarball?

Comment: I used pgAdmin to create an empty database before executing that command. But it would be better to create it in the same commend or extra commands before executing the restore command. ANy idea?

Comment: I also tried via `cmd /c "docker exec database-container pg_restore --username=postgres --no-password --dbname=employee --verbose C:\backup\employee.tar"` but not worked.

Comment: How did you create the tarball?

Comment: I dıownloaded it from a site I did not get or take it as backup from db.

Comment: Can you copy & paste the first 10 lines into your question as code, please?

Comment: Yes, but there is not 10 lines an I already paste the related parts. I do not use command to create an empty database before running pg_restore.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I concluded to drop and create db before restore. If you have a better solution you are welcome and I will give a try.

```
docker exec database-container bash -c "dropdb -U postgres employee"
docker exec database-container bash -c "createdb -U postgres employee"

cmd /c "docker exec -i database-container pg_restore -C -U postgres -d employee -v 
    < C:\\backup\\employee.tar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let `pg_restore` drop and recreate the database before restoring your backup by providing both parameters `--create --clean` together.

> --create
> Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting to it.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html